# Python - Получение ссылки и ее ID из текста

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как сделать так, чтобы в тексте искалась ссылка и после этой ссылки есть ID, и мне нужно эту ссылку получить.

**Пример:**
Сам текст: по этой ссылке https://сайт/aHkdr на ней вы можете узнать новую информацию.

То есть мне нужно получить саму ссылку и ID например `"aHkdr"` после нее, при том что ID и текст будет меняться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import re
from pprint import pprint
text = ('You should use index-url = https://pypi.python.org/simple rather than' 
'find-links in your config. This will replace the default rather than just '
'adding another option (which is what find-links does '
'http://pypi.python.org/master ).')

links = {link.rpartition('/')[-1]: link for link in re.findall(r'https?://\S+', text)}

links2 = [{'link': link, 'id': link.rpartition('/')[-1]} for link in re.findall(r'https?://\S+', text)]

pprint(links, indent=1)
pprint(links2, indent=1)

for item in links2:
  print(item.get('link'))

for item in links2:
  print(item.get('id'))

# {'master': 'http://pypi.python.org/master',
#  'simple': 'https://pypi.python.org/simple'}

# [{'id': 'simple', 'link': 'https://pypi.python.org/simple'},
#  {'id': 'master', 'link': 'http://pypi.python.org/master'}]

# https://pypi.python.org/simple
# http://pypi.python.org/master

# simple
# master
```

> В данном случае используется библиотека для работы с регулярными выражениями `re` для которой задается шаблон поиска, где искомая комбинация начинается с `http` после которой возможно будет `s` далее следуют `://` после которых неразрывная комбинация любых не пробельных символов. Метод findall находит все комбинации описанные шаблоном.
> Затем в процессе поиска при помощи метода строки `rpartition` мы получаем по разделителю '/' каждую ссылку на кортеж из 3х элементов, к примеру из `https://pypi.python.org/simple` мы получим `('https://pypi.python.org', '/', 'simple')` тоесть разбиваем по самому правому разделителю. Все это обернуто в генератор словаря (это я уже от себя добавил, мне так показалось юзабильней)

Comment: Спасибо, можете объяснить как это работает?

Comment: @LIFI, дополнил ответ пояснением

Comment: А вот если я получил ссылку и id, но я хочу вывести только ссылку, как тогда поступить если айди постоянно меняется?

Comment: @LIFI, дополнил ответ

Comment: большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Можно реализовать это подобным образом:

```
text = 'Вы можете перейти по этой ссылке https:// 
    сайтт/aHkdr на ней вы можете узнать новую информацию.'

split_text = text.split()

for i in split_text:
      if "http" in i:
          link = i

print(link)
```

И дальше уже сделать `link.split()` и взять последний элемент , в котором будет необходимый токен

Comment: Спасибо большое, не думал то что это так просто)